# How to unittest php array with different charset?

Tags: php, arrays, character-encoding, phpunit

Im trying to assert a function in which mycode converts `Windows-1252` code to `UTF-8` Example as follows:

```
function test($article){
       $result = mb_convert_encoding($article[0]['Description'], "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
retrun $result;
}
```

I'm trying to input a `Windows-1252` and assert its changes but its not working.

My Unititest:

```
$convertedArray = array(array('Description' => "an example pain— if you’re"));
$someString = $this->getMockBuilder('\Client')
            ->setMethods(['getArticle'])
            ->getMock();
        $someString->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getArticle')
            ->with('12345')
            ->will($this->returnValue($convertedArray));

        \client::set($someString);
```

Or

In simple: Im trying to input **$str = "an example painâ€” if youâ€™re";** and expect the function to convet it to UTF-8 and return **"an example pain— if you’re"** how can i do that?

Im getting the following error:

```
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
-    'record' => 'an example pain— if you’re'
+    'record' => 'an example painÃ¢â‚¬â€� if youÃ¢â‚¬â„¢re'
 )
```

Comment: If you create a file/fixture with the text and save it with Win1252 encoding, then do a `file_get_contents()` and proceed with the unit test?

Comment: @Loek will try that.! Thanks

Comment: I tried with file.. but haven’t tried with reading using file_get_contents(); used fileread operation instead.

Comment: Cool! I remember `file_get_contents()` to be binary safe so it should work. If not, let me know and I'll search further :)

Comment: I feel the problem is because of the Array() :( when we add to array it converts it as string so I can’t abld to convert back. If possible try my code and see if it works for array. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I've found an error in your converting function. Switch out the two encodings: https://3v4l.org/8rFKG

Comment: That looks good.. I will check with UnitTest. By sendings windows1252 and see my function return utf8 it’s should work.. but still not 100% confident.. hope it works thanks again.

Comment: @Loek ur code works but not for my scenario.. if u see my code.. my code gets WINDOWS-1252 and converts to UTF8.. if I change the encoding sadly  it won’t work for me :(

Comment: @Loek it worked :) thanks. Do u like to create a answer for the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad I coulp help! Answer for reference:

It seems that you changed up the parameters of the `mb_convert_encoding()` function, unfortunately.

```
// Change this
$result = mb_convert_encoding($article[0]['Description'], "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");

// To this
$result = mb_convert_encoding($article[0]['Description'], "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");
```

See your expected working code in action [here](https://3v4l.org/8rFKG).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to guarantee an encoding for your test strings do the following:

1. Make sure you know what encoding you're writing the code in, eg: UTF8.

   - This will be in your editor settings.
2. Convert your test string from that encoding to your target.

   - `$test_1252 = mb_convert_encoding($test_utf8, 'cp-1252', 'utf-8');`
3. Encode the test string in something 7-bit-safe, like base64.

   - `echo base64_encode($test_1252);`

Now you have a string that you can safely copy/paste in/out of whatever file you want while maintaining its encoding.

eg:

```
$test_utf8 = "an example pain— if you’re";
$test_1252 = mb_convert_encoding($test_utf8, 'cp1252', 'utf-8');

var_dump(
    $test_utf8,
    $test_1252,
    bin2hex($test_utf8),
    bin2hex($test_1252),
    base64_encode($test_utf8),
    base64_encode($test_1252)
);
```

Output:

```
string(30) "an example pain— if you’re"
string(26) "an example pain� if you�re"
string(60) "616e206578616d706c65207061696ee2809420696620796f75e280997265"
string(52) "616e206578616d706c65207061696e9720696620796f75927265"
string(40) "YW4gZXhhbXBsZSBwYWlu4oCUIGlmIHlvdeKAmXJl"
string(36) "YW4gZXhhbXBsZSBwYWlulyBpZiB5b3WScmU="
```

Comment: Answers like this make me wish there was a 'Save for later reference' button  on SO :)